# MYSQL INSERT problem

Tags: mysql, insert

```
$body = $_POST['post'];
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
$date = date("Y-m-d");
require('php/connect.php');

if($submit)
{

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (`id`, `body`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '".$body."', '".$date."')");
header("Location: index.php");
}
```

I do not understand why this isn't working, I took the query straight from PHP my admin after writing a line simular myself before hand and it still isn't working, can someone hep?

Comment: What does your schema look like?

Comment: comment out your `header("Location: index.php");
` and append `or die(mysql_error());` at the end of your query code that will show you what went wrong

Comment: Even though I've commented out my header I'm still being redirected to index.php O_O

Answer (score 2):

you definitely should escape your input values using mysql_real_escape_string

With mysql_error you can print out an error message but you need the connection identifier as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I just suggest to handle mysql error

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (`id`, `body`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '".$body."', '".$date."')")
 or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

and if `id` is primary key that can not be null

you should escape user input using [**mysql_real_escape_string**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function.

What happen if I put `"that's it "` value in your `$body` input, your query will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out your header("Location: index.php"); and append or die(mysql_error()); at the end of your query code that will show you what went wrong. You should also "mysql_real_escape_string" your user input before inserting it into your database.

```
$body = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post']);
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
$date = date("Y-m-d");
require('php/connect.php');

if($submit)
{

$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (`id`, `body`, `date`) VALUES (NULL, '$body', '$date')") or die(mysql_error());
//header("Location: index.php");
}
```